# How to access the internet in a cordova ios application?

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova

I'm using HTTP requests to active php files on a server to draw in information from a database. The project works perfectly on the x-code simulator however on the device there seems to be no internet access for the app. My information from the database appears blank. It's as if the http requests aren't running.

Below is my config.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" id="http://yourdomain/GearSwipeTutorial" version="1.0.0" viewmodes="maximized">
<tizen:application id="rMZJXG1BgI.GearSwipeTutorial" package="rMZJXG1BgI" required_version="2.2"/>

<content src="index.html"/>
<feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.all"/>
<icon src="icon.png"/>

    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
    <access origin="http://cs1.ucc.ie" subdomains="true" />
    <access origin="http://www.webqr.com" subdomains="true" />
    <access origin="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" subdomains="true" />
    <access origin="http://code.jquery.com" subdomains="true" />
    <access origin="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" subdomains="true" />
    <access origin="http://fonts.gstatic.com" subdomains="true" />
    <access origin="http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/18/4/main.js" subdomains="true" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" version="0.2.3" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" /> // Change square braces to arrow braces.

    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection" />
    </feature>

    <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />

    <plugin name="Camera" value="CDVCamera" />


    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection" />
```

It works perfectly in the simulator and browser but not on the device. The function breaks at xmlhttp.onreadystatechange.

```
function importJson(str) {
               alert("1");
                     if (str=="") {
                        document.getElementById("top5").innerHTML="";
                        return;
                        alert("2");
                        }
                     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        alert("3");
                        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                        } 
                     else { // code for IE6, IE5
                                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                                 alert("4");

                            }


                            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                            alert("15");

                           if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                                    alert(xmlhttp.response);
                                    alert("5");
                                    data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response);
                                    receivedData(data);
                                    alert("hello");


                          }

                            }
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `http://127.0.0.1/*` instead of `http://127.0.0.1*/` also try using your system ip address.

Answer (score 0):

I dont thing there is anything specific in the phone gap which allow or disallow the internet access . The most important thing is `<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />` and  it is in the place for you .

I guess your device connection is too slow and your request in timing out  this could be the reason . Try to take device in the same network in which you are trying to access for simulator .

Comment: I am using the same wifi connection for the laptop which the simulator is running on and ios device.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using something like [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

```
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.open("get", "yourFile.txt", true);
oReq.send();
```

You probably need to use generic javascript functions because I don't think that ActiveX objects will work on all devices.

```
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```